# fan not working on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: overheating, fan

My laptop is Thinkpad-E430. I installed Ubuntu 14.04. I found it a little overheated， especially around the touchpad area. Then I launched the command "cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan" to see whether the fan is working. It displays:

```
status:     disabled
speed:      0
level:      0
```

Does it mean that the fan is not working? Or the fan is working but not detected?

Answer (score 0):

It says your fan is disabled, you need to go into your bios and enable it from there, it should work after that.

Comment: I have looked it up everywhere, but my bios doesn't have the fan option.